# How to remove the additional page created by the jasper report at the end of the report?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am new to Jasper Reports. I am using Jasper Report version 2.0.5 for creating PDF files for my project. I have a main report which displays the `Summary` and a subreport which displays the 'Collections'. The first page of the report displays the 'Summary' and all the other pages display the 'Collections'. I want to display 'Collections:' on its first occurrence in the report i.e. on the second page of the report and 'Collections: (continue)' on all the other pages at the top below the header.

It is working fine but the problem here is that an additional page is added at the last of the report with only 'Collections: (continue)' written.

I have tried using all the different properties like 'Remove line when blank' and 'Blank when null' but nothing works.

```
<columnHeader>
            <band height="28"  isSplitAllowed="true" >
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="false" isBlankWhenNull="true" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
                    <reportElement
                        x="3"
                        y="7"
                        width="277"
                        height="16"
                        key="textField-16"
                        positionType="Float"
                        isPrintRepeatedValues="false">
                            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{totalRecords} != new Integer(0))]]></printWhenExpression>
                        </reportElement>
                    <box></box>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Collections: " + (!$V{CollectionsPageNumber}.equals(new Integer(1))?"(continued)" : "")]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </columnHeader>
```

Page1:
[image: Page1]

Page2:
[image: Page2]

Page3:
[image: Page3]

Page4(additional page):
[image: Page4(additional page)]

Comment: Please share the jrxml file

Comment: The issue is resolved now. The problem was in the size of the band. On increasing the band size, the additional page was not included in the file. @Rathnayake, thanks for your concern.